# how to create a simple login page using Neutrinos Platform/

Tags: neutrinos-platform

How to create a simple login page using Neutrinos platform? That means it should be configured to a basic Neutrinos IDS. BASICALLY CONSISTING OF A BASIC LOGIN PAGE

Answer (score 0):

Neutrinos 7.0.2 version onwards, you can choose to use the IDS settings which by default supports Neutrinos IDS. Register your app name as a IDS client name in the settings tab post you create your app. This would take you to the login page at run time automatically.